# Deducing the type of a pointer non-type template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, non-type

I have a function which accepts as a non-type template parameter a pointer `O` to an arbitrary object (with linkage), like so:

```
Foo foo;

...

template <typename T, T* O>
ftype* make_function() {
    // do something with O
}
```

To pass the pointer to an `foo` object of type `Foo`, I need to call it like this:

```
make_function<Foo, &foo>()
```

However, I'd like to simply call it like `make_function<&foo>()`, i.e., have the type `Foo` of the pointer deduced, as it could be in similar patterns (e.g., if I was passing `foo` as an argument).

Here's a more [fleshed out example](https://godbolt.org/z/8U6asn) on Godbolt.

Answer (score 4):

C++17 allows

```
template <auto* O>
ftype* make_function() {
    // do something with O
}
```

Before that, you need indeed

```
template <typename T, T* p>
```

Macro can help to reduce verbosity at usage:

```
#define AUTO(p) decltype(p), p

// ...

make_function<AUTO(&foo)>();
```

Comment: Yeah I am currently using something along the lines of the macro solution, I should have said "non-macro". Unfortunately I'm targeting c++14.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: You need feature of version you don't have access. So you are limited with old syntax or available workaround (such as MACRO).

Comment: Right, thanks. I'll leave it open for a bit in case someone else has a clever solution.